# Efficient way to connect information between two dataframes based on factors in R (or how to avoid loops in R)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two large dataframes, one is called `Dates_only` and the other `Values`

```
   **Dates_only:**  
       ID    Quart_y  Quart
    1  1118  2017Q3   0.25
    2  1118  2017Q4   0.50
    3  1118  2018Q1   0.75
    4  1118  2018Q2   1.00
    5  1118  2018Q3   1.25
    6  1118  2018Q4   1.50
    7  1118  2019Q1   1.75
    8  1118  2019Q2   2.00
    9  1119  2017Q3   0.25
    10 1119  2017Q4   0.50
    11 1119  2018Q1   0.75
    12 1119  2018Q2   1.00
    13 1119  2018Q3   1.25
    14 1119  2018Q4   1.50
    15 1119  2019Q1   1.75
    16 1119  2019Q2   2.00
    17 13PP  2017Q3   0.25
    18 13PP  2017Q4   0.50
    19 13PP  2018Q1   0.75
    20 13PP  2018Q2   1.00
    21 13PP  2018Q3   1.25
    22 13PP  2018Q4   1.50
    23 13PP  2019Q1   1.75
    24 13PP  2019Q2   2.00
```

And the second dataset:

```
**Values**  
  ID   Day   Value
1  1118  0    7.6
2  1119  0    6.2
3  13PP  0    6.8
4  1118  0.14 7.1
5  1119  0.13 6.2
6  13PP  0.13 5.9
7  1118  0.20 6.8
8  1119  0.23 5.8
9  13PP  0.24 4.6
10 1118  0.27 6.5
11 1119  0.28 5.4
12 13PP  0.32 4.2
13 1118  0.32 6.3
14 1119  0.32 4.8
15 13PP  0.44 4.0
16 1118  0.47 6.0
17 1119  0.49 4.3
18 13PP  0.49 3.8
19 1118  0.59 5.9
20 1119  0.64 4.0
21 13PP  0.61 3.6
22 1118  0.72 5.6
23 1119  0.71 3.8
24 13PP  0.73 3.4
25 1118  0.95 5.4
26 1119  0.86 3.2
27 13PP  0.78 3.0
28 1118  1.10 5.0
29 1119  0.93 2.9
30 13PP  1.15 2.9
```

What I want to do is to create another column (a fourth) in the `Dates_only` called `Value_average`, and it will contain average scores extracted from `Values` dataframe from the column `Values$Value`.
Specifically, as you can observe in `Dates_only` the `Quart_y` represents quarters/year, the `Quart` quantify this with a number from `0.25:2`.
So, the pattern goes like this `Q3 - x.25, Q4 - x.50, Q1 - x.75, Q2 - x.00`.

In the second dataframe, `Values`, we have some scores that represent days of the year. The concept is that for days that have scores `0<Day<0.25` belong to the `2017Q3`, days with scores `0.25<Day<0.50` belong to `2017Q4`, and days with scores `1.00<Day<1.25` belong to `2018Q3`.

I want for each ID from `Dates_only` dataframe to find the average of the `Values$Value` numbers that belong to the appropriate time frame: 
For `ID=1118` and for `2017Q3` the 'Values$Day' elements that are between `0<Day<=0.25` are `(0, 0.14, 0.20)` and the equivalent `Values$Value` are `(7.6, 7.1, 6.8)` so the `Dates_only$Value_average` is going to be `7.16`. The next will average values for days `0.25<Day<=0.50` etc.

```
   **Dates_only:**  
       ID    Quart_y  Quart Value_average
    1  1118  2017Q3   0.25   7.16
    2  1118  2017Q3   0.50   6.27
```

The code that I have used is:

```
Dates_only$Value_average <- 0

for (i in 1:length(Dates_only$ID)){
  id <- as.character(Dates_only$ID[i])
  quart <- as.numeric(Dates_only$Quart[i])
  quart_prev <- quart-0.25

  count_d <- 0
  sum_val <- 0

  for (k in 1:length(Values$ID)){
    if (id==as.character(Values$ID[k]) 
        && quart>=as.numeric(Values$Day[k]) 
        && as.numeric(Values$Day[k])>quart_prev){
      sum_val <- as.numeric(Values$Value[k]) + sum_val 
      count_d <- count_d + 1
    }
  }
  av_value <- sum_val/count_d
  Dates_only$Value_average[i] <- av_value
}
```

Is there a more efficient code to do that in very large datasets (over 300K observations)? I am pretty sure there is but my novice skills on R do not help a lot.

To replicate the two dataframes:

```
Dates_only <- data.frame(ID=c('1118','1118','1118','1118','1118',
                                 '1118','1118','1118','1119','1119',
                                 '1119','1119','1119','1119','1119',
                                 '1119','13PP','13PP','13PP','13PP',
                                 '13PP','13PP','13PP','13PP'),
                            Quart_y=c('2017Q3','2017Q4','2018Q1','2018Q2',
                                      '2018Q3','2018Q4','2019Q1','2019Q2',
                                      '2017Q3','2017Q4','2018Q1','2018Q2',
                                      '2018Q3','2018Q4','2019Q1','2019Q2',
                                      '2017Q3','2017Q4','2018Q1','2018Q2',
                                      '2018Q3','2018Q4','2019Q1','2019Q2'),
                            Quart=c(0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.00,
                                    0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.00,
                                    0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.00))

Values <- data.frame(ID=c('1118','1119','13PP','1118','1119','13PP',
                          '1118','1119','13PP','1118','1119','13PP',
                          '1118','1119','13PP','1118','1119','13PP',
                          '1118','1119','13PP','1118','1119','13PP',
                          '1118','1119','13PP','1118','1119','13PP'),
                     Day=c(0,0,0,0.14,0.13,0.13,0.2,0.23,0.24,0.27,0.28,
                           0.32,0.32,0.32,0.44,0.47,0.49,0.49,0.59,0.64,
                           0.61,0.72,0.71,0.73,0.95,0.86,0.78,1.1,0.93,1.15),
                     Value=c(7.6,6.2,6.8,7.1,6.2,5.9,6.8,5.8,4.6,6.5,5.4,
                             4.2,6.3,4.8,4,6,4.3,3.8,5.9,4,3.6,5.6,3.8,
                             3.4,5.4,3.2,3,5,2.9,2.9))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can accomplish almost all of this using the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

Values %>% 
  mutate(Day = ifelse(Day == 0, 0.01, Day)) %>% 
  mutate(Quart = ceiling(Day / 0.25) * 0.25) %>% 
  full_join(., Dates_only, by = c("ID", "Quart")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Quart, Quart_y) %>% 
  summarise(Value_average = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives you:

```
       ID Quart Quart_y Value_average
   <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>         <dbl>
 1   1118  0.25  2017Q3      7.166667
 2   1118  0.50  2017Q4      6.266667
 3   1118  0.75  2018Q1      5.750000
 4   1118  1.00  2018Q2      5.400000
 5   1118  1.25  2018Q3      5.000000
 6   1118  1.50  2018Q4           NaN
 7   1118  1.75  2019Q1           NaN
 8   1118  2.00  2019Q2           NaN
 9   1119  0.25  2017Q3      6.066667
10   1119  0.50  2017Q4      4.833333
# ... with 14 more rows
```

See below for a breakdown of each line of code for any questions:

---

```
# Start with your `Values` data frame
Values %>% 
  # Recode `Day` that are '0.00', as they currently will be excluded from 
  # the rule 2017Q3: 0<Day<=0.25
  # I picked 0.01 arbitrarily to fit this rule
  mutate(Day = ifelse(Day == 0, 0.01, Day)) %>% 
  # Now round all `Day` values up to the nearest 0.25
  mutate(Quart = ceiling(Day / 0.25) * 0.25) %>% 
  # Now join the two data frames using a `full_join`
  # A left_join may also be used if you are uninterested in NA's
  full_join(., Dates_only, by = c("ID", "Quart")) %>% 
  # Finally, designate groupings to calculate the mean values 
  # for each ID for each quarter
  group_by(ID, Quart, Quart_y) %>% 
  summarise(Value_average = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You can combine the `mutate`'s

Comment: True, but my personal preference is to keep as is.  As is, it's easier to move things around / edit code line by line in my experience.

Comment: Thanks David! I have to go through dplyr's documentation and explore it further.